# Proving an elementary proposition about modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ring-homomorphism

I want to prove the following:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ is an abelian group then $M$ is an $R$-module iff there exists a ring homomorphism $f: R \rightarrow End_Z(M).$

**My professor said that its proof is elementary but I can not see that, could someone  push me in the right direction of the proof please?**

**EDIT:**

An abelian group $M$ can be given the structure of $R$-module if and only if there exists a ring homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon R\to\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)
$$
If $M$ is given a structure of $R$-module, then the homomorphism $\varphi$ is defined by $\phi(r)\colon x\mapsto rx$. Conversely, given the ring homomorphism $\varphi$, we can define $rx=\varphi(r)(x)$.

**Is this a valid proof?**

Comment: Assume that you have a ring homomorphism $f: R \rightarrow End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$. How would you define, in $M$, the multiplication by some $a \in R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you the corresponding maps/actions and you can then verify that they satisfy the desired properties:
Let $M$ be an $R$-Module. Define $f:R\to \operatorname{End}_{\Bbb Z}(M)$ by $f(r)=g_r$ where $g_r:M\to M$ is given by multiplication by $r$, i.e. $g_r(m)=r\cdot m$. Using the module properties check that this $f$ gives a well-defined homomorphism.
Conversely given such a morphism $f:R\to \operatorname{End}_{\Bbb Z}(M)$, define the $R$-module structure on $M$ by $r\cdot m= f(r)(m)$ for $r\in R,m\in M$. Here as well we can check that this indeed defines an $R$-module structure.
Furthermore these two constructions are inverse to each other.
**Edit:** For $r,s\in R$ we have: $$(r+s)\cdot m:=f(r+s)(m)=(f(r)+f(s))(m)=f(r)(m)+f(s)(m)=r\cdot m+s\cdot m$$
and $$(rs)\cdot m=f(rs)(m)=(f(r)\circ f(s))(m)=f(r)(f(s)(m))=f(r)(s\cdot m)=r\cdot (s\cdot m)$$
The other properties can be proved similarly.

Comment: I edited my question could you please check the edit?

Comment: I do not see the proof of conversely.

Comment: Your proof in the edit is fine. Where are you stuck in the proof of conversely?

Comment: Are you saying in conversly that RM = M? could you show me the proof of  this please?

Comment: No, given a ring homomorphism $f:R\to\operatorname{End}_{\Bbb Z}(M)$ we want to define an $R$-module structure on $M$, i.e. we want to define an $R$-scalar multiplication on $M$ that satisfies certain properties: For $r\in R$, $m\in M$ we need to define $r\cdot m$ and we do that using $f$. I will edit the answer and include a proof  of certain properties of the scalar multiplication